# How do you pass a column value to a function that returns a table

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure that takes an int and returns a table that's used in a left join.  I'd like to create a view instead of calling the procedure.  Is there any way to do this? I'm getting "multi-part identifier couldn't be bound"

Example:

```
select users.*, extended.* 
from users left join dbo.getaggregateproperties(users.Id) as extended
on users.userid = extended.extendedid
```

Comment: I assume you mean table-returning function, not stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://SELECT%20users.*,%20extended.*%20FROM%20users%20CROSS%20APPLY%20dbo.getaggregateproperties(users.Id)%20as%20extended%20WHERE%20users.userid%20=%20extended.extendedid) instead

```
SELECT users.*, extended.*
FROM users
CROSS APPLY dbo.getaggregateproperties(users.Id) as extended
WHERE users.userid = extended.extendedid
```

Comment: I would just add  if OP wants to see NULLs use OUTER APPLY  +1